# Cannot connect to Xdebug from PhpStorm after updating to WSL2

Tags: php, windows-10, phpstorm, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Environment

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 1909
- WSL: Ubuntu (18.04. 5)
- PHP: 7.3
- PhpStorm: 2020.2

I heard that WSL2 can work with 1909, so I upgraded my Ubuntu from WSL1 to 2.
When I tried to debug with PhpStorm after setting it up, "Connection was not established." was displayed.

And then I looked at the log,

```
[2640] Log opened at 2020 xx-xx: xx: xx
[2640] I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost: 9001.
[2640] W: Creating socket for 'localhost: 9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[2640] E: Could not connect to client.: - (
[2640] Log closed at 2020 xx-xx: xx: xx
```

was displayed.

I tried changing various Xdebug settings, but I couldn't connect to any of them.

Since WSL2, the IP address has been different, but I heard that it is now possible to use localhost, so I changed it to localhost, but it still didn't work.

Is it impossible to use WSL2 at present? Or is there any way?
Thank you in advance.

/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
;extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/20190902"                                           
;zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

/etc/php/7.3/cgi/conf.d/20-xdebug

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
 
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

phpinfo:

```
php -info | grep -i xdebug                    
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
    with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 1000 => 1000
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => On => On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/xdebug.log => /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9001 => 9001
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Interpreters:
[image]

Debug:
[image]

Comment: 1) Partially related comment (for your info, so you have better understanding): it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. 2) `localhost` is wrong here (`xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"`) -- it needs to be the actual IP address of the host ... which can change every time you boot your OS (yeah...). Try this article: maybe it will allow you to automate IP address detection this way: https://www.silverf0x00.com/setting-up-xdebug-for-phpstorm-on-windows-wsl2/ or google for "xdebug WSL2"

Comment: 3) You may also try `xdebug.remote_connect_back = on` -- may work in auto-detecting the IP address (the value of `xdebug.remote_host` in such case will be ignored, at least in 2.9 version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to get the IP address of your Windows host. You can do this by inspecting your networks settings or simply via `ipconfig` in a DOS prompt (not inside WSL2).

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Speedport_XXX
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXX
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : XXX
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : XXX
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : XXX
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.115
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%8
                                       192.168.2.1
```

In my example case it is the value of IPv4 Address which is `192.168.2.115`.

- In PhpStorm go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug
- Open Advanced Settings and enable "Pass required configured options ..."
- Select your PHP > CLI interpreter
- Click the folder icon on "Configuration Options"
- Hit "plus" and add a new entry
- Put as key `xdebug.remote_host`
- Put your local IP address (`192.168.2.115`) as value

This will Xdebug inside WSL2 allow to connect back to your windows host.

Comment: Thank you! All the dots are starting to connect